# How to map Spring MVC controllers to a specific folder?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm working on a project using Spring MVC, Spring Boot, Gradle and Thymeleaf. I was wondering if there's a way to avoid controllers returning lengthy String paths to a specific view in a subfolder?

My views are currently in `resources/templates/views/home/`

```
public String index( Model model ) {
    return "views/home/index";
}
```

I'm looking to only have to return something like `home/index` or `home/someotherpage` for the HomeController.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by defining `templateResolver` bean in your configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class TemplateConfig {
    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        final SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }
}
```

Now you can use your return `index` page in your controller as:

```
public String index( Model model ) {
    return "home/index";
}
```